# How to stop remaining actions on timer stop?

Tags: c#, timer

I have a button with mouse click event handlers.
When the button is pressed (mouse down), a timer is started to simulate other clicks with a delay. The click runs a bitmap transformation, e.g. rotation of 0.5 each time.

When the button is released (mouse up), the timer is stopped.

Code in Button class :

```
private void TreatMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    // Following clicks
    _repeteTimer.Tick += (senderTick, eTick) => {
        _repeteTimer.Stop();
        PerformClick();
        _repeteTimer.Interval = _nextDelay;
        _repeteTimer.Start();
    };
    // First click  
    PerformClick();
    _repeteTimer.Interval = _firstDelay;
    _repeteTimer.Start();
}

private void TreatMouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    _repeteTimer.Stop();
}
```

Code in window :

```
btnRotation1.Click += (sender, e) => PHOTO_Treat(1);

private void PHOTO_Treat(int delta) {
    if (!_inProgress) {
        _photoRotation += delta * 0.5F;
        PHOTO_Show();
    }
}

private void PHOTO_Show(){
    if (_inProgress) return;
_inProgress= true;

    // Make image treatments ...

    _inProgress = false;
}
```

The problem is that several transformations occur again after the button is released, if the transformation take long time.

How can I suppress remaining ?

Comment: Maybe you can try some other scenario. To example, have `Timer` always on. Set some flag, when mouse button is pressed while inside, and reset, when released. If flag set, `Timer` will do rotation, otherwise it will not. Another thing is repaint. Rather **change the angle always** and initiate repaint with `Invalidate()` (which means *please, repaint this control as soon as you have time*) and proceed angle inside `OnPaint`, than what you did (it's like you are not using timer to sync rotation, but rely on repaint, which is like if you don't use timer -> depends on pc performance).

Comment: use OnPaint instead of a timer can be usefull to adapt the repainting to the pc performances. I keep this idea in mind. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you have some serious threading issues.

You could check whether the button is still down by checking `_repeteTimer.Enabled`.

Also, add a lock. Even if just to be safe.

```
private readonly object SyncRoot = new object();

private void PHOTO_Show()
{
    if (!_inProgress)
    {
        // race for a lock
        lock (SyncRoot)
        {
            // check button state
            if (!_repeteTimer.Enabled)
            {
                // button was released
                return;
            }
            // else
            try
            {
                _inProgress = true;
                MakeImageTreatments();
            }
            finally 
            {
                _inProgress = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the "lock" statement seems to be a good solution, there is no accumulation of extra "clicks" and the final delta is good (not incremented too much). Thank you !

Comment: It helps to understand that a timer doesn't wait for the `Tick` handler to complete before it starts counting again. That's why you need to write your own synchronization logic. This is a pretty common scenario, so make sure you don't forget it.